# Android: How to restart activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I made 2 activities.
e.g] MainActivy and MediaActivity.
If user click home button in MediaActivity, App will hide.
I want launch MediaActivty again when screen on.

Comment: Judging by the answers already given, I don't think anyone understands your question. I realize that English is not your mother tongue, but you will need to find a way to explain what you want (try pictures if you can't find someone to help you with English)

Answer (score 0):

Open the gmail app, tap on an email to show it's contents. You have now gone from one activity (email list) to another (email details). Press the home button. Now open the gmail app again. Voila! You have returned to the email you selected.

What you ask for is the default behavior of an Android app. Unless you do something like call finish() in your onPause() method in MediaActivity you should return to MediaActivity when you open the app again.

If your app doesn't behave like this I suggest that you post some code.

Comment: "I want launch MediaActivty again when screen on." Sounds like the OP wants to not have to press the app widget to open it

Comment: private BroadcastReceiver mScreenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
    wasScreenOn = false;
    wakeUp();
    
   } else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
    wasScreenOn = true;
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(i);
   }
  } 
  
 };

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your activities the following way :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Put your own code here.
    }
}

public class MediaActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Put your own code here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is Up Navigation / Ancestral Navigation(if I understood it correct). Refer to this guide: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Othewise, if you want to have multiple instances of an activity, it's `android:launchMode` property should be set to `standard` in manifest. Refer:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: I want lunch activity from Background Mode.

Comment: I want lunch Activity in Background Mode. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: You want to run some code in background mode. Activity = Screen. Activity is always created with an intention to show something (foreground).

For background processing of code, use services.